# Texteditor Like Khanacademy JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was wondering how I would go about making something like what Khanacademy has.

If you check out the link below they basically have a text box where you can input text and then depending what "keywords" you put it will highlight them, for example if you type function it will return with the word function in the colour blue. But if you do stuff like rect() it will draw a rectangle in the screen next to it. I want to do something like this but with HTML, so depending if you put certain keywords it would make it a certain colour and then it will output your code in the screen next to it as actual HTML. I'm guessing you could do something like an iFrame for the output but not sure about the rest.

Link: https://www.khanacademy.org/cs/programming/drawing-basics/p/intro-to-drawing

I checked out stuff online but can't find anything like this.

Another thing you could relate is the code editor on codecademy.com.

If you need more information let me know!

This is my last resort, I've been looking for 2 months D:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good syntax hightlighter you can use is CodeMirror (http://codemirror.net/). It is very easy to implement and get text from it, change colors, etc.

I understand you also want to be able to allow for programming in the textbox. A simple way too allow this without creating your own code parser would be to use javascript code in your textbox. You can then use javascript's `eval()` function on the text in the textbox to execute this javascript.

The only thing you would have to do then is to code your own functions like `rect()` as javascript functions in your html page. For drawing functions like `rect()` and others you can already use the HTML5 canvas object (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_canvas.asp). You could then draw this canvas in an iframe like you suggested or just simply in another div.

I hope this will give some inspiration or get you started.

**EDIT:** I have provided a small example: (you browser must support HTML5 for this to work)

```
<html>

<link rel=stylesheet href="http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css">
<script src="http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/addon/edit/matchbrackets.js"></script>

<style>
  .CodeMirror { height: auto; width: 500px; border: 1px solid #ddd; }
  .CodeMirror-scroll { max-height: 200px; }
  .CodeMirror pre { padding-left: 7px; line-height: 1.25; }
  #drawing { position:absolute; left:550px; top:10px; border: 1px solid #ddd; width:500px; height: 400px; }
</style>

<textarea id=code>
// Drawing test
Rect(20,20,100,100);
</textarea>

<div id="drawing">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="400"></canvas>
</div>

<br><input type="button" onclick="eval(editor.getValue())" value="Run" />

<script>
    var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("code"), {
      lineNumbers: true,
      mode: "text/javascript",
      matchBrackets: true
    });
</script>

<script>
<!-- Your functions go here -->
function Rect(x,y,width,height)
{
    var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.rect(x,y,width,height);
    ctx.stroke(); 
}
</script>

</html>
```